# Proper handling when returning a function value and comparing

Tags: jquery, function, coffeescript, jquery-validate

Is it bad practise to call a function which returns a value directly in a comparison?

I have this coffeescript code that works fine in my dev environment, but on the server it doesn't work. It looks like this.

```
$.validator.addMethod "fullName", (value, element) ->
  num_words = (value) ->
    parts = value.split(" ")
    remove_empty = $.inArray("", parts)
    parts.splice remove_empty if remove_empty isnt -1
    return parts.length
  num_words(value) > 1
, "Please enter your first and last name"
```

JQuery validate is calling this function num_words and returning the result of the condition `num_words(value) > 1`

Could it be failing because I'm calling the function directly in the comparison instead of assigning it to a variable first?

Comment: Show the rest of the code!  The `.validate()` method, the HTML and anything else to demonstrate what you're talking about.  Does this work using standard JavaScript syntax or is this solely a CoffeeScript issue?

Comment: maybe you could use `Array.prototype.filter` or `$.grep` instead. seems more like what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/53kh1L4s/2/ based on the fiddle by @Sparky

Comment: in coffeescript: http://jsfiddle.net/53kh1L4s/3/

Comment: Maybe you could come back and give us some feedback on the answers you've received so far.  Thanks.

Comment: @sofancy, you should just delete and repost the question rather than completely replace it so that your only two answers are now totally disconnected from the original.

Answer (score 1):

everything in coffeescript is considered an expression, so there is nothing wrong with you use of the language, but I think there might be some edge case you might be missing with you code.

Since you are using coffeescript, would you consider the following blueprint (you may need to tweak the validation slightly for your particular use case):

```
window.validators ?= {} # just a namespace

class validators.NameValidator
  isValidString = (s)-> /\w+/.test(s)

  constructor: (@names)->
    @validStrings = $.grep(@names, isValidString)

  isValid: -> @validStrings.length > 1

# wrapper for the class
checkNames = (value, element)->
  validator = new validators.NameValidator(value.split(" "))
  validator.isValid()


$.validator.addMethod("fullName", checkNames, "Please enter your first and last name")
```

working fiddle based on @sparky's http://jsfiddle.net/53kh1L4s/4/

Comment: The OP is using the jQuery Validate plugin... so not sure what/why you'd need to be doing all that.

Comment: @Sparky the validator plugin still requires a function that returns a true/false evaluation.`checkNames` just simply makes the logic readable and encapsulated. 'all that' i guess is a matter of opinion, since the code I read in the question seems like 'why are you doing all that' to me.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work.  Just wondering why we need to do that when he just needed to clean up the original code a bit.  And if you're the one who down-voted me, an explanation is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your CoffeeScript [converted](http://js2coffee.org) back into plain JavaScript is this...

```
$.validator.addMethod("fullName", function(value, element) {
    var num_words;
    num_words = function(value) {
        var parts, remove_empty;
        parts = value.split(" ");
        remove_empty = $.inArray("", parts);
        if (remove_empty !== -1) {
            parts.splice(remove_empty);
        }
        return parts.length;
    };
    return num_words(value) > 1;
}, "Please enter your first and last name");
```

Now that I can read it better (*I don't know CoffeeScript*), I don't understand why it's so verbose.  You don't need the `num_words` function within the `fullName` method function.  Despite the verbosity, [as plain JavaScript, it still works](http://jsfiddle.net/53kh1L4s/1/).  Apparently, this is a case that CoffeeScript just cannot handle as you've written it.

However, this version works exactly the same, but it's shorter and more concise...

```
$.validator.addMethod("fullName", function(value, element) {
    var parts = value.split(" "),
    remove_empty = $.inArray("", parts);
    if (remove_empty !== -1) {
        parts.splice(remove_empty);
    }
    return parts.length > 1;
}, "Please enter your first and last name");
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/53kh1L4s/**

I don't see a problem here, as after all, since it's only being called from one place, there is absolutely no advantage to having a `num_words` function within the `fullname` method function.

---

and [converted back](http://js2coffee.org) into CoffeeScript...

```
$.validator.addMethod "fullName", ((value, element) ->
    parts = value.split(" ")
    remove_empty = $.inArray("", parts)
    parts.splice remove_empty  if remove_empty isnt -1
    parts.length > 1
), "Please enter your first and last name"
```

**Working DEMO (CoffeeScript):  http://jsfiddle.net/xyxq2c73/**

Comment: I downvoted you because I felt like your comment 'Now I can read it better' was pretty sarcastic. When you commented back I saw the link to the demo and realized you had put a lot of work into this but I was unable to change my vote. I'm sorry :/ I'm sure you have a ton of great answers. I'll go upvote a couple. That being said, this is far from idomatic coffeescript.

Comment: @JedSchneider, I honestly don't understand why you'd think that was sarcasm.  I don't know very much about CoffeeScript so naturally I can read it better after it's been converted back into JavaScript.  I'll edit my answer and the voting will unlock.  It's not really about the number of rep points, it's about downgrading a technically acceptable answer that, like you said, I put some effort into.

Comment: probably me just being defensive. my apologies.

Comment: @Sparky You answered my question, poorly. I didn't need a step by step convert to js, remove modularity, convert back to coffeescript. I was asking about the behaviour of returning functions in a condition, not how to do it. You answered my question in this sentence `"Despite the verbosity, as plain JavaScript, it still works."` But I take responsibility for this because I used the code I was working on at the time as an example. I should have rewritten it in a simplified version to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @sofancy, if you didn't need it converted to demonstrate that your modularity is what's breaking your CoffeScript version, then you should have tried that yourself and mentioned it in the OP.  Not down-vote me for trying to answer an ambiguously written question or for simply doing what you should have done in the first place.